# Foreign key Problems

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a table and I am experiencing some trouble.

I have two tables called `Pay` and `Owed`
So I have a table Pay with the following primary key

```
CONSTRAINT pk_columns PRIMARY KEY (nameofClient, amounttoPay);
```

And Owed table with the foreign Key:

```
CONSTRAINT en_submission2 FOREIGN KEY (nameofClient, amounttoPay) REFERENCES Pay (nameofClient, amounttoPay);
```

So in essence what I am trying to ask is how to I add a foreign key to a table from another table whose primary key is composite? Is my syntax wrong? What do I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: what doesn't work? Are you getting any error messages? And welcome to stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yeah I am getting an error message. It say cannot add or update child a child row. Thanks

Comment: You can have composite PKs and FKs.

Comment: @Ester: always prefer copy-pasting **the real** error message over your own interpretation

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest some schema changes to pull the client into its own table and the use id fields for your keys (is the amount a client owes really unique? ).  So you'd have something like:
Clients
- Id (int, not null, pk)
- Name

Pay
- Id (int, not null, pk)
- ClientId (fk to Client.Id)
- AmountToPay

Owe
- Id (int, not null, pk)
- PayId (fk to Pay.Id)
- AmountToPay